# Make comments visible on post only for registered users of certain type

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a post on which I would like to make comments visible only to the registered set of customers. With the Roles (Members?) plugin I can add custom membership types. Let's say I have the page `Office support`, the custom member type `Office customer`. I would like to make the comments on the `Office support` page visible only to the Office customers. How can I do that?

Comment: if(customer_type == "Office customer"){//Display whatever..} .. ??

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you determine your members when they have logged in with **$_SESSION**
for example:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_SESSION['member']){
     if($_SESSION['member'] == 2){
     ....
     }
}
?>
```

with a simple if/else combination you can choose show the content or not.

**Note**: above codes are so simple and without considering security measures.